# How i can serialized data to json with drf serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have data models like:

```
from django.db import models


class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name


class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class CourseParticipant(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='courses', on_delete=None)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='students', on_delete=None)
    completed = models.BooleanField(null=True, default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course
```

I have some serializer like:

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('name', 'end_date', 'start_date')
```

I need return data in json like:

```
{
    "courses": [
        {
            "name": "Math",
            "end_date": "2019-06-26",
            "start_date": "2019-06-26",
            "participant_students_count: 10
        }
    ]
}
```

How I can get "participant_students_count" and return its data in json with other fields.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) of DRF serializer field. Also, see about how to follow [Backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) access of Foreign key relationship.

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    participant_students_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('name', 'end_date', 'start_date', 'participant_students_count')

    def get_participant_students_count(self, obj):
        return obj.courseparticipant_set.count()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    participant_students_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_participant_students_count(self, obj):
        return CourseParticipant.objects.filter(course=obj).count()

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('name', 'end_date', 'start_date', 'participant_students_count')
```